# Missing symbol divmodsi4 when building for armv6 iPhone

Tags: iphone, linker, armv6

When using Xcode 4.2 to build an armv6 architecture program, I am getting a weird linker error:

Symbol not found for architecture armv6

___divmodsi4

Which is a math function symbol included with llvm

What could be the cause of this problem? Is this because of a bug in xcode, or is it because armv6 is not able to use this? (Note: Compiling the same code for armv7 does not cause this issue.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try change the compiler to APPLE llvm.